# Analyzing a PHP program

Tags: php

I have been giving a PHP program to work on. However, this program has been worked on for years by several diffrent people. Things have been removed and added over time. But most of the files are still there.

I was wondering is there is a tool out there that can analyze a PHP program. feed it index.php for example and this tool will check and see witch files are called and used so i can remove all the dead wood that is no longer beeing used.

I was planning on writing it myself, but someone else might already have done something like this.

Any suggestions are welcome, Thx!
Mike

Comment: PHP is ill-suited for such analysis, since it allows you to write `include $_GET['file']`. Not that you should ever do such a thing, but it means that it's *impossible* to cover all cases in which a file may be included...

Comment: This path is ripe with false positives. You can get an overview with a source analyzer looking for filename cross-references. Capturing the dynamic ones with certainty is very difficult. You can however use http://pecl.php.net/package/inclued to determine the actually included files reliably. And [PHP Depend and others](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4156157/tool-for-php-code-analysis) may provide more helpful lists.

Answer (score 3):

As deceze mentioned you cannot guarantee to find all referenced files as they may be dependent on user input. However the simplest way is to use a grep tool (there is a "windows grep" application you can download, if that's your platform) and find all occurrences of "include" and "require". If you come accross the situation mentioned by deceze (include or require followed by a variable name) the file needs manual inspection, but if there is a file name specified, you can add that to the "used list".

Perhaps not the most effective solution, but fast and intuitive.

Comment: Let me give that a try, it's ok if it's not 100% accurate, if i can get 90% of all the dead code out of it it's still a big improvement.

Comment: A big gotcha here would be watching out for autoloaders.

Answer (score 1):

You have couple options, one to use xdebug and basically debug your application, while you are stepping through you ll find the files being used.

Another is brute force:)) start deleting files one by one and check the app if it s broken or not. if there is a lot to test, this might take a while.

And if you are searching for an app, search for dependency checker, there are corps that uses these kinda apps to check dependencies between services, like amazon.

Comment: I will try out the xdebug see what that does. The brute force is not realy an option with the size of the program and the amount of options in it. That would take forever.

Comment: it s a debugging tool, you can step in and out of files and classes, easily.

Answer (score 1):

You can get an array of all files which are included by calling the [get_included_files](http://nl.php.net/get_included_files)( ) function. You can append each file with the following code, which will write all included files to an array in "included.php", the easiest way to do so is using [auto_append_file](http://php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.auto-prepend-file). Next, click through the whole application. When you're done all the files that were included will be in included.php, so you can spot which files aren't actually used.

```
<?php
function writeIncludes( array $includes ) {
  $filename = __DIR__ . '/included.php';

  $output = "<?php\nreturn ";
  if( file_exists( $filename ) ) {
    $files = include( $filename );
  }
  else {
    $files = array( );
  }

  $files = array_merge( $files, $includes );
  $output .= var_export( $files, true );

  file_put_contents( $filename, $output );
}

writeIncludes( get_included_files( ) );
```

Of course, this script is not useful for debugging other than your current sitation, but it should get you up and running fast enough. It might be ugly, but it'll do its job.